# Hide expandable SliverAppBar on scroll down, but do not expand until reached to top

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-appbar, sliverappbar

I want to hide the `SliverAppBar` on scroll down, but I don't want it to expand unless user is at the top, I also want non-expanded `SliverAppBar` to show when user is going up, but it shouldn't expand when user reaches to top.

`pinned: true` causes `SliverAppBar` never being hidden.
`floating: true` causes `SliverAppBar` to expand when user scrolling up around mid scroll (should only expand when the user reaches to top)

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/dPSTaDdX3qI
In the first half of the video, small part of the app bar doesn't show when user is scrolling down.

`SliverAppBar` is pinned in the second half video, so it never hides.

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  const TestScreen({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.black,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: [
          // sliver app bar
          const SliverAppBar(
            expandedHeight: 300,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            floating: false,
            pinned: false,
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text("Show on scroll down without expanding", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
          ),
          // sliver items 1
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  height: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // sliver items 2
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  height: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // sliver items 3
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  height: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // sliver items 4
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  height: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),

          // sliver items 5
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                left: 20,
                right: 20,
              ),
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.deepPurple[400],
                  height: 400,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```